# How to put the icon on the tab and also make it appear on the Favorite (bookmark) side of the web browser

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how can i add the Icon of my webpage specially on the bookmarks side of the web browser, for example y have already added this line in html:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/Natural.jpg" sizes="196x196">
```

when im talking about the bookmark side, im referring to this, for example in safari:

[image]

As you can see there are sites that already have the logo or icon like Apple, Github... ; But there are another that not, like JsFiddle, CodePen...

I dont know what is that part of html or whatever that it left to make it appear there.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You should set favicon to your site. here is a [generator](http://www.favicon-generator.org/) you can use, after you have created your icon add these tags to your html

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

make sure to set the right path for the icon.

Comment: hmm, I have used your tool and it dropped me this link and meta tags:do I have to add all of these and

Comment: you have to add the `.ico` file to your content folder and the meta tags to your website body. the browser should reference those as you wished